# From tkinter windows , I need to fetch the text frame font,colour and save it and I need to recreate the frame again

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import sqlite3 as sql
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.font import Font

Times_New_Roman = ('Times New Roman', 12)
Calibri = ('Calibri', 14)
Century_Gothic = ('Century Gothic', 16)
Verdana = ('Verdana', 20)

global index
global curr_index

curr_index = 0
index = 0

global tk_window_dict
tk_window_dict = {}


def on_window_click(event):
    global curr_index
    focused_widget = event.widget.focus_get()
    if focused_widget:
        curr_index = focused_widget.winfo_toplevel().title()
        print("Current Window Title:", curr_index)
        return curr_index
    else:
        print("No focused window.")
        return 0


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.connection = sql.connect('sticky_notes.db')
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            self.cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sticky_notes
                             (title text, notes text)''')
            print("self.connection to Database")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


class StickyNoteWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        global index
        self.db_notes = SqlLite()
        print("Index", index)
        tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"] = Tk()
        tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"].geometry('300x200')
        tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"].attributes('-alpha', 0.95)
        tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"].configure(bg='#ffffff')
        self.mainloop = tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"].mainloop

        tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"].title(f"{index}")
        main_frame = Frame(tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"])
        main_frame.pack()

        second_frame = Frame(main_frame)
        second_frame.pack()

        third_frame = Frame(main_frame)
        third_frame.pack()

        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.heading_{index}"] = Entry(second_frame, width=300)
        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.heading_{index}"].insert(1, "Enter Title Here!")
        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.heading_{index}"].pack()

        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{index}"] = Text(third_frame,
                                                              height=10,
                                                              width=90)
        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{index}"].pack()

        menubar = Menu(tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"])
        tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"].config(menu=menubar)

        global curr_index
        tk_window_dict[f"second_window_{index}"].bind("<Enter>", on_window_click)
        print("curr_index", curr_index)
        print(tk_window_dict)
        for item,value in tk_window_dict.items():
            try:
            #if 'second_window' in item:
                print(value.get())
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                continue
        file_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.new_window)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=lambda: self.db_notes.add_notes())
        file_menu.add_command(label="Update", command=lambda: self.db_notes.update_notes())
        file_menu.add_command(label="Delete", command=lambda: self.db_notes.delete_notes())
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

        style_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

        style_menu.add_command(label="Bold", command=lambda: self.change_second_frame_style("Bold"))
        style_menu.add_command(label="Italics", command=lambda: self.change_second_frame_style("Italic"))
        style_menu.add_command(label="Underlined", command=lambda: self.change_second_frame_style("Underline"))

        menubar.add_cascade(label="Style", menu=style_menu)

        font_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

        font_menu.add_command(label="Times_New_Roman", command=lambda: self.change_second_frame_style("Times_New_Roman"))
        font_menu.add_command(label="Calibri", command=lambda: self.change_second_frame_style("Calibri"))
        font_menu.add_command(label="Century_Gothic", command=lambda: self.change_second_frame_style("Century_Gothic"))
        font_menu.add_command(label="Verdana", command=lambda: self.change_second_frame_style("Verdana"))

        menubar.add_cascade(label="Font", menu=font_menu)

        color_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        color_menu.add_command(label="Purple", command=lambda: self.change_background_color('#dbcdf0'))
        color_menu.add_command(label="Green", command=lambda: self.change_background_color('#d0f4de'))
        color_menu.add_command(label="Yellow", command=lambda: self.change_background_color('#fcf6bd'))
        color_menu.add_command(label="Pink", command=lambda: self.change_background_color('#f2c6de'))
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Color", menu=color_menu)

    @staticmethod
    def new_window():
        NewStickyNote()

    @staticmethod
    def old_window(title):
        OldStickyNote(title)

    @staticmethod
    def change_background_color(color):
        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].configure(background=color)

    def change_second_frame_style(self, style):
        if style == "Bold":
            tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].configure(font=Font(weight="bold"))
        elif style == "Italic":
            tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].configure(font=Font(slant="italic"))
        elif style == "Underline":
            tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].configure(font=Font(underline=True))
        elif style == "Times_New_Roman":
            tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].configure(font=Times_New_Roman)
        elif style == "Calibri":
            tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].configure(font=Calibri)
        elif style == "Century_Gothic":
            tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].configure(font=Century_Gothic)
        elif style == "Verdana":
            tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].configure(font=Verdana)


class SqlLite:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = Database()
        self.title = None
        self.notes = None
        global curr_index

    def add_notes(self):
        self.title = tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.heading_{curr_index}"].get()
        self.notes = tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].get("1.0", "end-1c")
        if not self.title or not self.notes:
            messagebox.showerror(message="ENTER REQUIRED DEmTAILS")
        else:
            self.db.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO sticky_notes VALUES (?, ?)", (self.title, self.notes))
            messagebox.showinfo(message="Note added")
            self.db.connection.commit()

    def delete_notes(self):
        choice = messagebox.askquestion(message="Do you want to delete all notes?")

        if choice == 'yes':
            sql_statement = "DELETE FROM sticky_notes"
        else:
            self.title = tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.heading_{curr_index}"].get()
            self.notes = tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].get("1.0", "end-1c")
            if not self.title or not self.notes:
                messagebox.showerror(message="ENTER REQUIRED DETAILS")
                return
            else:
                sql_statement = "DELETE FROM sticky_notes WHERE title=? AND notes=?"
                self.db.cursor.execute(sql_statement, (self.title, self.notes))
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Note(s) Deleted")
        self.db.connection.commit()

    def update_notes(self):
        self.title = tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.heading_{curr_index}"].get()
        self.notes = tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{curr_index}"].get("1.0", "end-1c")
        if not self.title or not self.notes:
            messagebox.showerror(message="ENTER REQUIRED DETAILS")
        else:
            sql_statement = "UPDATE sticky_notes SET notes=? WHERE title=?"
            self.db.cursor.execute(sql_statement, (self.notes, self.title))
            messagebox.showinfo(message="Note Updated")
            self.db.connection.commit()


class NewStickyNote:
    def __init__(self):
        global index
        index = index + 1
        self.obj2 = StickyNoteWindow()
        self.obj2


class OldStickyNote:
    def __init__(self, title):
        global index
        index = index+1
        self.title = title
        self.db = Database()
        self.obj2 = StickyNoteWindow()
        self.obj2

        sql_statement = "SELECT notes FROM sticky_notes where title ='%s'" % self.title
        self.db.cursor.execute(sql_statement)

        self.row = self.db.cursor.fetchall()
        self.db.connection.commit()

        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.heading_{index}"].delete(0, END)
        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.heading_{index}"].insert(1, title)
        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.heading_{index}"].pack()

        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{index}"].insert(INSERT, str(self.row[0][0]))
        tk_window_dict[f"StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt_{index}"].pack()


class FirstWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = Database()

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title(f"{index}")
        self.window.geometry('300x200')
        self.window.attributes('-alpha', 0.95)

        self.window.configure(bg='#ffffff')
        self.mainloop = self.window.mainloop

        sql_statement = "SELECT title FROM sticky_notes"

        self.db.cursor.execute(sql_statement)
        row = self.db.cursor.fetchall()

        if len(row) <= 0:
            NewStickyNote()
            messagebox.showerror(message="No note found")
        else:
            all_notes = {}
            for k, i in enumerate(row):
                all_notes[i[0]] = Button(self.window, text=str(i[0]), command=lambda pi=i[0]: OldStickyNote(pi)).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FirstWindow()
    mainloop()
```

I am new to tkinter and python
Working:
File --> New (Creates a new sticky note)
File --> Save (Saves the sticky note)

Can someone help me in below issues,

Note: I have updated the code as per the suggestion Now I am facing below errors

1]I need to fetch the StickyNoteWindow.inputtxt frame font, color [Now I am able to get only text] of the frame and save it when the window closes, and I need to recreate the window again when the app opens can someone help me on how I can achieve this functionality.

Comment: If you want a general code review you should post in codereview.stackexchange.com.  Better to limit posts here to a specific question. 
But to start an answer to your first one, based on a quick look, it seems that you're never instantiating StickyNoteWindow. It's a class - you should be making individual instances of it for each note by calling `StickyNoteWindow()`, and then binding the actions in each window to its own instance. But instead you're just calling methods on the class itself, and so constantly overwriting the same slots with new values and throwing the old ones away.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the code now and able to map the cursor to the right window , please review. Now i am not able to get the text frames font,colour and save it so i can recreate the frames and windows once closed. Is there a way you could help me work this functionalioty

Comment: You have total control of the sticky note, so I wonder why you cannot store the styles, like font, color, etc, when you create and update the note.

Comment: yes but I want it to be fetched and recreated as I save the note on that particular window,  I am able to get the details using text_frame.cget("font"), thank you for the input